# Being able to add times such as 2:39 instead of decimal numbers using VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a Time Sheet Calculator Application and just need to find out how to add numbers that are in hourly form.  For example 2:39 (two hours and thirty nine minutes).  I know how to create code for simple addition of decimal numbers, but does VB 2010 have some kind of way of adding hours and returning a number in hourly form.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the TimeSpan type ....

```
Dim ts1 As New TimeSpan(2, 39, 0)
Dim ts2 As New TimeSpan(3, 40, 0)
Dim ts3 = ts1 + ts2
MessageBox.Show(ts3.ToString)
```

i.e 2:39 + 3:40 = 6:19